# simple dictionary for getting value

Tags: python

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = range(1,4)

dicts = dict(zip(names, values))

this_name = 'b'
```

How to get the value 2 here?

Comment: What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Do you mean get number by name? just `print dicts[this_name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code at the end:

```
print dicts[this_name]
```

Answer (score 2):

`dicts.get(this_name,"")` `""` is the default value if there isn't a key `b` in the dict

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
>>> dicts[this_name]
2
>>> dicts.get(this_name)
2
```

Take a look here how dictionary works [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)